# why css class missing suffix in react production mode using vite?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, vite

I have a project developed in React and MUI, using vite package tool. I have a problem that in development mode, the CSS styles are normal, but when I deploy using vite build, the CSS style are missing some suffix, which cause wrong styles.

Development CSS:
[image]
[image]

Production CSS:
[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why would the lack of the suffix "cause wrong styles"?

Comment: the viewLatestButton class is not take effect, and is override by css-14d438r

Comment: That has nothing to do with the naming of the CSS class. The difference between the two cases is the order in which they are defined. In dvl the viewLatestButton styles are in a `<style>` element, but in prod they are pulled from a `.css` file. That difference doesn't necessarily matter, but I suspect the `.css` file is being loaded in the `<head>` element prior to where the MUI styles are injected, but in dvl the viewLatestButton styles were probably being injected after the MUI styles in the `<head>` element. When CSS specificity is the same, the styles defined last will win.

Comment: yes, it is related to the order of my custom CSS class and MUI CSS class, how to change the CSS order in production mode?

Comment: I find a doc here: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order

Comment: I have get it right using :<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>, thanks